# Two rates of change

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, related-rates

Two mice (say $A$ and $B$) eat a piece of food. The rate of consumption for $A$ is proportional to amount of food left(Proportionality constant = $2$) and rate of consumption for $B$ is proportional to amount of food eaten by $A$(Proportionality constant = $1/2$ ).

Find the time it takes the food to be finished.

Also find the time after which the rate of consumption of both mice is same.

**My Attempt**

Let $F_A$ and $F_B$ be the amount of food eaten by A and B after time t.

$\frac{dF_A}{dt}=-2\{N-(F_A+F_B)\}$

$\frac{dF_B}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}F_A\Rightarrow \frac{d^2F_B}{dt^2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{dF_A}{dt}$

So eliminating $F_A$ and $\frac{dF_A}{dt}$ we get

$\frac{d^2F_B}{dt^2}-2\frac{dF_B}{dt}-F_B+N=0$

Are my deductions correct. How to proceed further now

Answer given is $1$ time unit and $0.66$ time units

Comment: 1) Solve the ODE for $F_B$ with the initial conditions $F_B(0)=0$ and $F_B'(0)=0$ (the latter follows from $F_B'=(1/2)F_A$). 2) Solve $F_A(t)+F_B(t)=N$. 3) Solve $F_A'(t)=F_B'(t)$.

Comment: I have just realized that your first equation has a sign error. It should be $\frac{dF_A}{dt}=+2\{N-(F_A+F_B)\}$.

Comment: I was missing $F'_B(0)=0$ and of course the sign error. I realize now that with increase in time $F_A$ increases so putting a minus sign is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per what Gonçalo said I followed his advice.

Let $N$ be the amount of food in the beginning.

$$\frac{dF_A}{dt}=2\{N-(F_A+F_B)\}$$

$$\frac{dF_B}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}F_A\Rightarrow \frac{d^2F_B}{dt^2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{dF_A}{dt}$$

So eliminating $F_A$ and $\frac{dF_A}{dt}$ we get

$$\frac{d^2F_B}{dt^2}+2\frac{dF_B}{dt}+F_B=N$$

$$e^t\frac{d^2F_B}{dt^2}+2e^t\frac{dF_B}{dt}+e^tF_B=Ne^t$$

$$\frac{d^2(e^tF_B)}{dt^2}=Ne^t$$

Integrating twice

$$e^tF_B=Ne^t+Ct+D$$

$$F_B=N+(Ct+D)e^{-t}$$

Clearly $F_B(0)=0$ and $F'_B(0)=0$

so we have $$F_B=N-(1+t)Ne^{-t}$$

and $$F_A=2Nte^{-t}$$

When the food is finished we have $$F_A+F_B=N$$

Substituting for $F_A$ and $F_B$ in above equation we get $t=1$

To find the time after which the rates of consumption are equal we obviously put

$$F'_A=F'_B$$ to obtain $$t=\frac{2}{3}$$